# adding total for each bar in stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

how to show the count and total for each bar seperatedly
[image: sample image]

```
 ggplot(dealflow_summary_fiscal_yr,aes(x=Total,y=Type,fill=status))+
      geom_bar(stat='identity',width=0.2)+theme_classic()+
      geom_text(aes(label = stat(x),group = Type),stat = "summary",fun = sum,vjust = .20,hjust= 1)+
      theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),axis.ticks = element_blank(),legend.position = "bottom",
            axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", size = 10, angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
      labs(x="", y="", fill="")+
      scale_fill_manual(values=c("#284a8d", "#00B5CE"))
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: kindly look the image that is the expected output

Comment: with the help of this code i m getting only total for both closed open but i need to show the count for closed,open,and total

Comment: while doing this its throwing the error like It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.@RonakShah

Comment: @Fariya You can just run `dput(dealflow_summary_fiscal_yr)` and edit and paste the complete output in your post.

Comment: kindly modified the data for more clarification while i am doing its throwing an error

Comment: I think your code is showing labels for total only and not for open and close.

Comment: ya exactly @RonakShah and thanks for editing the code

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the totals for each `Type` separately and plot them in separate `geom_text`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Total_data <- dealflow_summary_fiscal_yr %>% 
                 group_by(Type) %>% summarise(Total = sum(Total))

dealflow_summary_fiscal_yr %>%
  group_by(Type, status) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(Total)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x=Total,y=Type,fill=status)+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',width=0.2)+
  theme_classic() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Total)) +
  geom_text(data = Total_data, aes(x = Total, y = Type, label = Total), 
            inherit.aes = FALSE) + 
  theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.x = element_text(face = "bold", color = "black", 
                                   size = 10, angle = 45, hjust = 1))+
  labs(x="", y="", fill="")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#284a8d", "#00B5CE"))
```

You might need to adjust the labels using `hjust`, `vjust` in `geom_text` based upon your complete data so that they are at correct position.

Comment: Thanks for the code but is there any other way to calculate this inside the ggplot

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to get the same graph using only ggplot.

Comment: its ok Ronark Shah thanks for your valualble time

Comment: while doing vjust dont know why i am getting double values